# Scala sql dataframe merge with update data

Tags: scala, dataframe, merge, union

I have two SQL Dataframes: I want to merge them, keep old lines, new ones, and updated. In python I do:

```
pd.concat([df1, df2]).drop_duplicates('Key', keep='last')
```

How can I do this in Scala?